# How to save the state of checkbox in flutter. It should remain checked or unchecked even if we navigate to another page or close the app

Tags: flutter, dart, checkbox, provider, state-management

How to save the checkbox state means when we checked it,it should remain checked even if we navigate through ought or close the program in flutter.
Here I have used provider to save the state Please guide how to save checkbox state once we checked or unchecked it in flutter.below is my code:

main.dart file-

```
import 'dart:developer';

 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

    import 'package:samplecheckbox/checkprovider.dart';

    import 'package:samplecheckbox/myhomepage.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MultiProvider(providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => CheckProvider()),
  ], child: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Create a Checkbox',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

provider.dart file-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CheckProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool _checkbox = false;
  void checkValue() {
    _checkbox = !_checkbox;
  }
}
```

myhomepage.dart file-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:samplecheckbox/checkprovider.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool _checkbox = false;
  bool _checkboxListTile = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Create a Checkbox'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Checkbox(
                  value: _checkbox,
                  onChanged: (value) =>
                      context.read<CheckProvider>().checkValue(),
                )
              ],
            ),
            
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence/key-value It will allow you to store your  checkbox value even if you close the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) to store your key-value pair data in a flutter.

**To Store data:**

```
// Obtain shared preferences.

final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

// Save an boolean value to 'repeat' key.

await prefs.setBool('isCheckboxChecked', true);
```

**To Get Data:**

```
final bool? isChecked = prefs.getBool('isCheckboxChecked');
```

Answer (score 0):

if your `chick box` values does not care of server then use `shared_preferences`

if your `chick box` values does care of server then `shared_preferences` will never help and you need to return bool value from your server every time you visit that specific page .

if you need to save the values within the app usage then you need to use global bool value